# IE will not seek audio/webm file

Tags: ffmpeg, internet-explorer, webm

I'm trying to create a WebM audio file that will play back and seek in all browsers using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag and MIME type `audio/webm`. I've found workarounds to get this to work in all browsers, but they are a bit clunky and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

I found this page to test browser support in various browsers (IE9 goes into quirks mode on that page, but if you switch to IE9 standard it will allow you to run the tests):
http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/
Note: this page's sample WebM file also plays but does not seek in IE.

I'm using a recent version of ffmpeg to encode.

IE9+/FF/Chrome browsers play but only Chrome seeks using the the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i src.wav dest.webm
```

When I added cues to the file, Chrome/FF was able to seek but IE could not.

```
ffmpeg -i src.wav -dash 1 -reserve_index_space 512 dest.webm
```

Finally I ended up adding a tiny video to the file to get all the browsers to work.

```
ffmpeg -stats -y -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=2x2:r=1 -i src.wav -shortest dest.webm
```

Likely, IE9+ only looks at the video key frames to handle seek and ignores any 'cues' in the audio.

My question is: am I missing anything or is this the workaround I have to go with? I'm certainly not an expert in WebM or ffmpeg so maybe someone else has figured this out or knows of a different workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't support Internet Explorer and neither should you. If it works on IE11 just move on with your life.

"On January 12, 2016 Microsoft announced end of support for IE10, IE9, and IE8"

https://www.xfive.co/blog/stop-supporting-ie10-ie9-ie8/